# Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document. Cookie error with subdomains

Tags: angular, google-chrome, cookies, session-storage

I have an Angular Application running on a subdomain `abc.domain.com` which calls a page in an iframe from `xyz.domain.com`. It was working all fine until a recent chrome update started to block third party cookies by default.

I am getting this error:

`Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.`

I can't load the contents of `xyz.domain.com` without cookies and that is possible only when I go to my chrome settings and select "Allow all cookies".

This will break the app for all my users and I can't expect them all to "Allow all cookies" as that in itself is a security risk from the user's point of view.

Is there a workaround for this? What can I do from my end to ensure the application runs fine? Since the domains are children of the same root domain, I hope there must be something to whitelist `xyz.domain.com` to read from `abc.domain.com`.

I am using ngx-cookie-service to manage cookies.

Comment: Your error related to SessionStorage - not with cookie.  
Cookies created for domain abc.com are valid for xyz.abc.com.  
Session/local Storage data is bind to the domain.

Comment: @PavelDubenko I see. What is the fix for this?

Comment: Fix - not to use sessionStorage and use cookie for 2nd level domain(abc.com) to store client's data :)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44802